# What operation is $\circ$?

Tags: group-theory

Given the following exercise:

"Consider the operation $\circ$ defined on $G_4 =\{ 0, 1, 2, 3\}$ by Table 3. Check whether it satisfies each of the three axioms from the definition of a group, and decide whether it is a group."

Table 3:

[image]

The properties of a group:

$1$. Asssoiativity: for any $a, b, c \in G_4$, we have $a\circ (b\circ c)= a\circ (b\circ c)$

$2$. Identity: for any $a \in G_4$, we have $a\circ e = e\circ a=a$

$3$. Inverse: for every $a \in (G_4,\circ ) $, theres is an inverse $a^{-1}$, such that $a\circ a^{-1}=a^{-1}\circ a=e$

Previosly I have concluded whether the sets $(G_4,+)$ and $(G_4,*)$ are groups by doing the following:

[image]
[image]

But I dont know what the $\circ$ operation for Table 3 is doing. Since we are working with numbers and not functions I am stuck trying to figure this out. I know that to find the inverses I can check if there's a value in every row that's equal to the identity value $e$, but I cannot find the identity value because I'm stuck wondering what the operation is doing. How do I read from Table 3 if it is a group or not?

Comment: $\circ$ is exactly the operation given by the table, no more, no less.  It is not addition mod $4$, or multiplication mod $4$, or anything familiar like that.  The only question is whether it is a group operation.  So find out whether it has an identity (this should be pretty quick), and determine what that identity element is.  Then find out whether each element has an inverse—that is, a corresponding element with which it combines via the operation to yield the identity element. (cont'd)

Comment: The tricky one is associativity.  But the fact that there are two $3$'s in the $2$ row is highly suspicious, especially given that $3$ is its own inverse.  Can you come up with three values for $a, b, c$ such that $(a \circ b) \circ c \not= a \circ (b \circ c)$?  If you can, you will have shown that $\circ$ is not associative and hence not a group operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment explains, the table itself is the defining mechanism for the operation. You are familiar with definitions for $+$, and then understand how to make a table from that. Likely, that understanding is misguiding you here. Here, the defintion of $\circ$ just *is* that table. Want to know what $a\circ b$ is? To find out you are supposed to look up where row $a$ and column $b$ meet in the table.

This operation does not make a group. $\circ$ing by $3$ is not a one-to-one map. So $3$ would not have an inverse.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a group, since $2\circ 2=3=2\circ 3$; the [Latin square property](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_has_Latin_Square_Property) is not satisfied.

Comment: Which axiom does not hold? I think the OP wants to prove it in that way.

Comment: @manooooh The cancellation property, which follows from the group axioms (see the link given) is not true. $2\circ 2=2\circ 3$ gives $2=3$ after left cancellation by the inverse of $2$. And $2=3$ is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

There's no $1$ in the last two rows.  But left translation by any element of the group should be a permutation of the group elements.